# How to fallback on git cloning in bash?

Tags: shell, git

I want to automate some setup tasks. When a team member writes `setup` which is our internal command, a couple of things would be done.

One of those things is to make sure the latest version of our `infra` repository is either pulled or cloned onto his laptop.

But if he does not have the `infra` repository cloned, I want to clone it based on his permission.

In other words here's what I want:

```
# This command would run if he has write access
git clone git@github.com:company/infra

# If the above command failed, I want to run this command
git clone https://github.com/company/infra
```

How can I run the second line, only if the first line failed?

Comment: Have a look at **exit codes** and how to use them in shell scripting (e.g. via `$?`).

Answer (score 3):

Combine the commands with `||`:

```
git clone git@github.com:company/infra || \
git clone https://github.com/company/infra
```

See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440) for details.